# Naming a Graph (Graph Theory)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, naming

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[acteur/.style={circle, fill=black,thick, inner sep=4pt, minimum size=0.2cm}]
\node (A) at (5,12) [acteur][label=right:0]{};
\node (B) at (8,11) [acteur][label=right:1]{};
\node (C) at (9,9) [acteur][label=left:2]{};
\node (D) at (8,7) [acteur][label=right:3]{};
\node (E) at (5,6) [acteur][label=below:4]{};
\node (F) at (2,7) [acteur][label=right:5]{};
\node (G) at (1,9) [acteur][label=left:6]{};
\node (H) at (2,11) [acteur][label=right:7]{};
\path (A) edge [loop above, thick] node {} (0);
\path (B) edge [loop above, thick] node {} (1);
\path (C) edge [loop above, thick] node {} (2);
\path (D) edge [loop above, thick] node {} (3);
\path (E) edge [loop above, thick] node {} (4);
\path (F) edge [loop above, thick] node {} (5);
\path (G) edge [loop above, thick] node {} (6);
\path (H) edge [loop above, thick] node {} (7);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It occur an error when I change

```
label 0 to label (0,0,0), label 1 to label<br/> (0,0,1) ... and so on
```

like this

```
\node (A) at (5,12) [acteur][label=right:(0,0,0)]{};
\node (B) at (8,11) [acteur][label=right:(0,0,1)]{};
... and so on
```

Comment: Are the `<br/>` in the code or an effect from a copy paste?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. - Why `(0,0,0)`...?

Comment: I guess you only need to put braces around the coordinates (or whatever the 3-tupels are) `\node (A) at (5,12) [acteur][label=right:{(0,0,0)}]{};`.

Comment: You are right need only to put braces thanks

Comment: @Marvin is your question solved? If yes please accept the given answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! If you place some sensitive character like `(`, it might be misinterpreted by the parser. In almost all situations putting things in groups, i.e. putting `{` and `}` around them, fixes the issue. And you can make your code *much* shorter using `\foreach`. (In principle, one `\foreach` loop is sufficient, but for the sake of the argument I am using two here.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[acteur/.style={circle, fill=black,thick, inner sep=4pt, minimum size=0.2cm}] 
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {90-\Y*45}] in {A,...,H}
{\node (\X) at (\Z:3) [acteur][label=right:{(0,0,\Y)}]{};}
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {A,...,H}
{\path (\X) edge [loop above, thick] (\Y);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]